# Provide training set and unlabelled set for weka

Tags: java, weka

Input and output format in weka has brought a big headache for me, as it only seems to take input from .arff and .cvs file. How do I directly convert java objects into `Instances`? Right now I am just writing Java objects into a .arff file and then read the file into weka `Instances`. Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Creating+an+ARFF+file) (in part) describes creating an Instance object.  Instead of writing your data to a .arff file and then reading it, you can skip the middle man.

You may find this question ([Define input data for clustering using WEKA API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093977/define-input-data-for-clustering-using-weka-api/20109536#20109536)) helpful for a concrete example of creating an Instances object from Java.